# In Build Ios App Error in the Error: Type 'Uint8List' not found. final Uint8List? pdfData;

Tags: flutter, dart, pdfview

[enter image description here][1]```none
** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
Writing result bundle at path:
/var/folders/05/0zbz_xz51wx802v29fcwqdgr0000gn/T/flutter_tools.SrQXp5/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirJWd2pK/temporary_xcresult_bundle
Error: Type 'Uint8List' not found.
final Uint8List? pdfData;
АЛЛАЛЛЛЛЛ
Error: Type 'Uint8List' not found.
final Uint8List? pdfData;

```
I found of this solution so if you have same error and stuck on this steps try this do the feedback
so just add this library limport. 'dart: typed _data' in your flutter_pdfview.dart


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s59kO.png
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jd1tC.png)

I Found of this solution so if you have same error and stuck on this steps try this do the feedback so just add this library in your flutter_pdfview.dart

import 'dart: typed _data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';